# What does "j'ai tennis" idiom mean?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, humour

I've spotted this on the self-service terminal in a French fast food restaurant:

[image]

What is the exact connotation of this? Does that mean a silly excuse for not being at work today?

Comment: It's originally a joke used to turn down an invitation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGUP2xQpgHc

Comment: You can replace tennis by whatever you want. Most popular in my friend group: aqua-poney.

Comment: [I have to return some videotapes.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8coOHhotXY)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As Alone-zee already commented, ***j'ai tennis*** is based on a well known humorous lame excuse to tell you won't be able to attend something.

The phrase means you have a planned tennis match or training.

The original sentence was ***Nan, j'peux pas, j'ai piscine*** (Nah, I can't, I have a swimming lesson), a running joke by [Laurent Baffie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_Baffie) muppet in *[Les Guignols de l'info](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Guignols_de_l%27info)* in the nineties (*Nulle part ailleurs* - Canal+).

Nowadays, *piscine* can be replaced by any activity, whether sports related or not.

In that particular case, the fast-food restaurant human interface designer joke was possibly inspired by a *Fédération Française de Tennis* [advertising campaign](http://www.fft.fr/actualites/fil-d-infos/la-nouvelle-serie-jpeux-pas-jai-tennis).

See also: *[J’ai bien compris qu’il ne s’agissait que d’une seule journée de tournage, seulement voilà, ce jour-là, **j'ai dentiste**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63421584#63421584)* (Blanche Gardin, 20 april 2023)

An English equivalent is *[Sorry, but I'm washing my hair that night](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=washing%20my%20hair)*

Comment: J'aurais bien voté, mais j'peux pas, *j'ai licorne*.

Comment: Et bien sûr ma préférée : je peux pas, j'ai aqua-poney.

Comment: so, it's humorous-but-lame, but not insulting?  (unlike, "sorry, I've got to wash my hair")

Comment: @davidbak It's never really insulting. It can be used to tease someone but is generally just a funny reply.

Comment: dans le même genre : "Désolé, je peux pas, je dois aller acheter le pain".

Answer (score 9):

While @Alone-zee is probably correct in that the specific cultural reference, it's a construct that could literally translated to:

> I have tennis

Which can be understood as either one going to play tennis or going to a tennis class but in any case, it's clear that the subject is going to play tennis.

Here, the second dimension to this is that there is a form of rejection using the pretext of 'having tennis'.

Finally, in this specific context, it seems that the device is experiencing issues and the software is displaying this message as a multi-layered joke.

1. It's acting as if the device is rejecting you;
2. Obviously, the device does not 'have tennis'