# Avoir (un) entrainement

Tags: articles

*Le journal de Carrie* de Candace Bushnell :

> Le pauvre, il doit avoir tellement l'habitude de se faire insulter que
> ça ne le vexe même plus.
>
> Quand même, je suis un peu ébranlée. Je ramasse mon sac de natation.
>
> -- J'ai **entrainement**.

Je sais qu'il est possible d'omettre l'article devant les noms abstraits. Mais *entrainement* est un évènement concret. Pourquoi alors il n'y a pas d'article dans *J'ai entrainement* ?

Answer (score 4):

C'est très courant d'omettre l'article pour le COD après "avoir" lorsqu'on parle d'une activité programmée et généralement récurrente, comme un cours, un entraînement de sport, une réunion professionelle, etc.

Ex:

J'ai cours de français tous les lundis.

J'ai entraînement de football.

On a réunion tous les mardis matins.

J'ai piscine (sous-entendu: j'ai cours de natation ou entraînement de natation - cette phrase est devenue une réponse humoristique quand on veut invoquer une fausse excuse pour décliner une invitation).

J'ai poney (sous-entendu: j'ai cours d'équitation à dos de poney - même excuse humoristique que "j'ai piscine").

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30869/what-does-jai-tennis-idiom-mean

Comment: Une variante : j'ai *aqua-poney*.