# Avoir un rendez-vous pour (un) scan

Tags: articles

Est-il possible d'omettre l'article devant *scan* à l'instar de [Comptines et Chansons **pour** **enfants**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8AXxssV6DyY)?

> J'ai un rendez-vous **pour scan** la semaine prochaine.

Comment: Je ne vois pas scan dans le lien. Il faut écouter toute la chanson ou quoi?

Comment: Ajouter « &t=xmys »  à l'url, à sa fin, sans espace de séparation ;  x est le nombre des minutes et y le nombre des secondes.

Comment: @LPH, il n'y a pas de mot "scan" dans la chanson. Je voulais dire "pour scan" comme "pour enfants". Il n'y a pas l'article entre les mots "pour" et "enfants", et je me demande si ce serait possible d'omettre l'article enre "pour" et "scan". Merci beaucoup pour l'astuce.

Answer (score 2):

Non, ou alors il faut supprimer plus que l'article :

> **J'ai scan** la semaine prochaine. (style relâché)

La phrase *j'ai un rendez-vous pour scan la semaine prochaine* entraînera un moment d'hésitation où on se demandera si *scan* n'est pas le nom du patient qui a ce rendez-vous. Elle sera finalement comprise mais la personne qui l'aura prononcée sera identifiée comme n'étant pas de langue maternelle française.

Note: On dit plus souvent *passer **un scanner*** qu'un ***scan*** en France.

Exemples (c'est moi qui graisse):

> CE QU’IL FAUT SAVOIR ET FAIRE AVANT UN SCANNER
> Lorsque vous prenez rendez-vous **pour un scanner**, munissez-vous de l’ordonnance du médecin.

Source: [Site officiel de l'assurance maladie.](https://www.ameli.fr/assure/sante/examen/imagerie-medicale/deroulement-scanner)

> – À part ça, demain matin, **j'ai scanner**. Pour vérifier que tout va bien dans mes intérieurs.

Source: [Didier Goux - *Journal de blog - Les joies du côlonialisme*](https://didiergouxjournal.blogspot.com/search/label/2015%20%E2%80%93%2009)

Comment: Oui, c'est comme dans ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49900/avoir-un-entrainement). Mais si je laisse "pour" ?

Comment: Pas vraiment, ou ce serait d'abord compris comme *J'ai un rendez-vous pour Rintintin la semaine prochaine*. D'autre part, j'ai l'impression qu'on dit plus souvent en France, *j'ai un rendez-vous pour un scanner* que *pour un scan*, ou alors *pour un scan 3D* (chez le dentiste).

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu "scanner" ici ; mon vét dit toujours un "scan", et le personnel à la réception aussi.

Comment: Ça ne m'étonne pas, ça n'a pas de sens en anglais, langue que les Québécois maitrisent bien mieux que les Français. Ils n'auraient pas laissé se produire la dérive qu'on a observé ici : *passer au scanner* →  *passer un scanner* →  *faire un scanner*.  Le mot *scan* est apparu plus tard chez nous et il est encore souvent associé aux scans de documents, comme avec une photocopieuse.

Comment: En plus au Québec on a le verbe calqué _scanner_ (pron. à la fr... é) pour _faire la lecture_, balayer des code-barres etc. Le _scanner_ (pron. angl. ou eur) c'est typiquement pour moi l'appareil qui numérise les documents. Oui, on a aussi les _documents scannés_, _scans de documents_ sans doute aussi.

Comment: @Earendelle On a aussi le verbe scanner /skane/ et le nom commun scanner /skanɛʁ/, c'est le deuxième qui est utilisé dans *passer un scanner*.

Comment: "J'ai scan demain"?  [passer un scan](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22passer+un+scan%22+site%3A.fr&oq=%22passer+un+scan%22+site%3A.fr&aqs=chrome..69i57.10203j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @Lambie C'est construit sur un modèle comme [_j'ai cours_](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/avoir-un-des-cours-avec-sans-article.2810603/).

Comment: @Earendelle Ha ha. Et j'ai faim. Est-ce que cela a cours aussi? :) [blague]

Comment: @Lambie Oui, intéressant _avoir faim_ est un syntagme possiblement plus figé, il est plus normal de ne pas avoir l'article avec de telles abstractions. voir LBU14@587 cc Oreste.

Comment: @Earendelle Je ne comprends pas pourquoi les autres francophones ne disent rien quand ils voient: J'ai scan demain, sans article.

Comment: @Lambie Parce qu'ils sont francophones, justement.

Comment: @Lambie 1min40s [*Ce soir j'ai transfusion*](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=136486651889067&_rdr&t=98)

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai cours, j'ai tranfusion peuvent de concevoir comme des activités répétées. J'ai scan, ça fait même pas zonard....

Comment: @Lambie [*Sinon, **j'ai radio des poumons aujourd'hui** (mamie me l'avait dit), écho du bide, écho du cœur et prise de sang demain.*](http://mesptitseins.canalblog.com/) et [*Cette semaine mercredi 19 08 **j'ai radio** pour me poser un fil en titane pour qu'on puisse opérer par la suite*](http://roselaine.canalblog.com/archives/2018/05/03/36373368.html)

Comment: @Lambie Tu auras compris que mon commentaire avait pour but de t'éclairer sur un modèle que tu ne semblais pas reconnaître. Tu auras compris que j'ai faim est usuel pour moi mais je suis Montréalais, donc un tour comme _j'ai cours_ je reconnais ça immédiatement comme étant métropolitain et je sais que c'est en usage mais je ne l'emploie pas, c'est tout. J'ai pensé à Oreste et comment savoir si on doit avoir un article. Je pense simplement à _avoir_ avec un objet comme _une pomme_.

Comment: @Earendelle Je viens à  l'instant de parler avec un médicin à Paris, qui est un ami à moi. Il vient de me dire: passer un scanner, oui. "Demain, j'ai scan".  Non, **Catégoriquement**. Alors...J'ai cours, j'ai faim. Partout où en parle français, bien sûr. Et ce qu'on trouve sur l'internet **dans des chats** sans articles, c'est précisément parce que ce sont des chats ou semblables à des chats.  Où les bizarreries prolifèrent.

Comment: @Lambie Son propos est valide pour lui et les gens qu'il côtoie peut-être. Des gens en autorité ou qui on une expertise, ce n'est pas plus leur rôle qu'à un autre de décider ce que les gens disent. Ça pourrait faire l'objet d'une question où le sujet serait mis en valeur.

Comment: @Earendelle Voyons ça de plus près. Tous les parlers, tous les dires des gens sont bons. Sans exception. Les gens parlent comme ils parlent. De là, à dire ici, que J'ai scan passe, oui, comme réponse: "Tu fais quoi demain" ? Tu vas passer un scanner ?" Réponse: "Oui, demain j'ai scan". Mais, cela est très familier et il ne me semblait pas que cela soit le niveau de langue ou registre dans la question d'Oreste.

Comment: @Lambie Toi et moi nous avons un point en commun ici, nous ne sommes pas Français et nous ne baignons pas dans le sociolecte. Tu as droit à cette opinion, ton médecin aussi et la personne qui contribue la réponse aussi. Je ne sais pas comment on parle couramment en France de ces sujets-là mais je vois des exemples en commentaire et dans la réponse.

Comment: @Lambie [Robert en ligne](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/rendez-vous) donne « Avoir, prendre (un) rendez-vous avec qqn. Donner (un) rendez-vous à qqn ». J'avais Usito dans ma réponse. Un sujet intéressant c'est la lexicalisation. Quand des trucs deviennent plus courants ou usuels peut-être qu'il se lexicalisent et qu'il est plus facile d'omettre l'article. Grevisse et Goosse ont une note vraiment intéressante à 587 sur comment ça change avec le temps. Certains trucs prennent maintenant l'article alors que non avant et vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Ce qui est plus usuel pour moi c'est *avoir rendez-vous* sans déterminant (*j'ai rendez-vous*, voir [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/rendez-vous) par exemple). Formellement, on [privilégiera](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870072) *examen de tomodensitométrie* ou *de tacographie* etc.. La préposition [*pour*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pour) dans le titre de l'album signifie *fait à l'intention de, destiné à* et *(faire) un scan* c'est un emploi un peu metonymique *faire un examen* (d'un type particulier ou impliquant un appareil particulier) et je trouve que ça milite en faveur du déterminant...

> J'ai rendez-vous (chez...) pour un examen (de...).
> Je dois [passer](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870072) un TACO, un rayon X, une échographie, une scintigraphie, une résonance magnétique demain (chez...) (inspiré par le GDT).

Je trouve « j'ai un rendez-vous *pour (un) scan* la semaine prochaine » inhabituel sans le déterminant.

Comment: Ce que j'ai entendu dans ma vie pour _passer un rayon X_ c'est probablement plutôt « passer une radio » pour radiographie.

Comment: Oui, "passer un rayon X" signifie "passer une radio", mais je n'ai jamais entendu le verbe "passer" dans ce contexte. Mon vét dit toujours "faire un scan". Et il dit toujours "scan", pas "examen de tomodensitométrie" ou autre chose. Je crois que l'on dit à la clinique "prendre un rv pour **un** scan", mais puisque mon cerveau omet les articles la plupart du temps, j'entends "prendre un rv pour scan". Et quand je parle, je les mets n'importe comment. :( Je ne peux pas dire aux gens "Attendez, je vais poser quelques questions sur SE.

Comment: @Oreste Bien sûr, passer **un scan**,  Mais on voit aussi sur des sites français, passer un scanner, ce qui est un peu bizarre puisque scanner, c'est la machine....enfin, voici l'usage: https://www.google.com/search?q=passer+un+scan+site%3A.fr&ei=j65NYqLiKJ2IptQP2LWUgAE&ved=0ahUKEwji5d6m3f_2AhUdhIkEHdgaBRAQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=passer+un+scan+site%3A.fr&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BAgAEBM6CAgAEBYQHhATOggIIRAWEB0QHkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFD0BliVImDlI2gBcAB4AIABS4gB6wOSAQE5mAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz Cela s'utilise en France, passer un scanner.

Comment: Au Canada, j'ai trouvé un scan: https://www.santelaurentides.gouv.qc.ca/fileadmin/internet/cisss_laurentides/Soins_et_services/Imagerie_medicale/REF_2017-01-01_Depliant_La_tomographie_axiale__scan_.pdf tomographie axial

Comment: @Oreste Mon expérience c'est que les médecins et les vetérninaires ne sont pas nécessairement les plus grands locuteurs du français et dans leurs manuels en français il n'y avait pas de _scan_. Avec _passer_ c'est courant pour moi, voir par ex. [ceci](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/sante/201802/14/01-5153922-les-appareils-dimagerie-medicale-tourneront-a-plein-regime.php) parce que _passer un examen_ est courant et un _scan_ n'est rien d'autre qu'un examen médical assisté d'un appareil relié à un ordi et qui mesure -graphie. _Prendre un rdv pour un scan_ m'apparaît bien courant à l'oral.

Comment: @Oreste Je ne sais pas quel conseil je pourrais te donner pour les articles. Je ne sais pas si l'idée de mettre l'article ou le déterminant à défaut d'avoir une raison de ne pas le mettre (tour figé ou autre) est un bon conseil. Ça prend tu temps mais la qualité de ton français n'est pas du tout en péril, bien au contraire. Peut-être que quand on sent qu'il y a ellipse ou réduction, ce n'est pas le temps d'omettre d'autres éléments en plus, je ne suis pas certain.

Comment: @Oreste Peut-être poser une question ou regarder aussi sur _Language Learning_, les articles semblent être un [sujet difficile](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/196).

Comment: Les médecins sont quand même au courant du langage et des usages medicaux, n'est-ce pas? Celui avec lequel je viens de parler m'a dit que normalement on utilise  l'article, à moins de se trouver sur des chats ou les textos.

Comment: Merci beaucoup :)